# 'React/RCTDevSettings.h' file not found

Tags: react-native

I try for del/install pod and node_module folder but the same issue occurred in xcode 
error Could not find the following native modules: RNCMaskedView, RNReanimated, RNScreens. Did you forget to run `pod install` ?

Comment: Do you use react-navigation?

Comment: Have you tried deleting Pods folder and pod lock file both? Delete them both and then reinstall pod.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure these 2 pods are included in your `PodFile`

```
pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'

pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
```

Then run `pod install --repo-update`

I got this working using React-native 0.62

Answer (score 3):

In my case adding

```
pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
```

solved the problem.